# Better way to write if sequence

Tags: php

I've a sequence of `if` statements and I can't figure a better way to write it here's it is :

```
$a='';$b='';$c='';
if($row->nA!=0){
        $a = $row->nA;
}
if($row->nB!=0){
        $b = $row->nB;
}
if($row->nC!=0){
        $b = $row->nC;
}
```

It simple but I can't find how write it better than this

Comment: If the `!= 0` tests are merely to determine if there is a value, you don't need to compare to `0`, you can simply say `if ($row->nA)`. But that depends whether it is important that they are not actually `0` versus simply being true or false. Also you can make this more readable by adding more whitespace, e.g. a space after each `if`, before each `{` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing completly wrong with your way.
If you want to write something else, try it like this:

```
$a = ($row->nA != 0) ? $row-nA : '';
$b = ($row->nB != 0) ? $row-nB : '';
$c = ($row->nC != 0) ? $row-nC : '';
```

But, like i said, there is nothing wrong with your way ;)

Comment: And when echoing them should echo eveyone seperatly I mean `echo $a; echo $b; echo $c` or is there another better way

Comment: Depends on how you echo your stuff to the browser. Are you doing this with a framework or "good old plain php". This is more a architecure question than a "general" question, it simply depends. Sometimes, it is good to just echo (or print or printf) your stuff, sometimes you may need something special to do that.

Comment: I'm using Codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

Sascha Presnac is right - there is nothing wrong with the way you're doing it. However, it might be useful if you tidy up your code a little.

```
$a = '';
$b = '';
$c = '';

if ($row->nA != 0) {
   $a = $row->nA;
}

if ($row->nB != 0) {
   $b = $row->nB;
}

if ($row->nC != 0) {
   $b = $row->nC;
}
```

Using extra lines to write your code is not a problem. It is better to be more spread out and easily readable, than scrunched up and hard to read :). But if you want to do it in as few a lines as possible then go for Sacha Presnac's approach :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have yo do it for a lot of variables you could do it with

```
$variables = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
foreach ($variables as $variable)
{
    $$variable = ($row->{"n" . strtoupper($variable)} != 0) ? $row->{"n" . strtoupper($variable)} : '';

}
```